# Android ViewFlipper - Prevent allocating all layouts inside ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper with a lot of *.xml layout items (108 to be exact) inside my activity layout and the problem is that when I start the application, all the layouts inside ViewFlipper are allocated.

Is there a way to prevent allocating all the ViewFlipper items at the startup and make it allocate only when viewflipper item is loaded ?

My main_activity.xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffececec"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <include android:id="@+id/pageMainWin"  layout="@layout/main_win" />
        // Other ViewFlipper items

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have 108 layout items?

Comment: You could essentially set the main layout item to `layout.setVisiblity(View.GONE)` while it is not in use and then provide a `View.VISIBLE` when you need it again if you really need to.  This will not consume resources until they are needed.  Such as when you pan left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a viewStub xml tag in your layout:

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <ViewStub
            android:inflatedId="@+id/pageMainWin"
            android:layout="@layout/main_win"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

Then in your code, programmatically inflate that extra xml layout resource

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.pageMainWin);
View inflated = stub.inflate();
```

more info on viewstubs here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html